# How can I see the list of previous elections while an election is active?

Tags: support, election

If you pop along to `/election` on an SE site not currently in election, you will see a list of the site's previous elections (for examples see [SU](https://superuser.com/election) or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/election)).

Currently `/election` on Gaming goes to the [currently active](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election) election page, which is fine, but how would I access the list of previous elections on Gaming at the moment? I'm interested in seeing which of the current crop of candidates ran in previous elections, what they said back then and so on.

---

I know that I can go to [`/election/1`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/1), [`/election/2`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/2) and so on, but this is doesn't feel like the correct way it should have to be done, and to find out what the last election was I'd have to start at 1 and keep going until I hit the current election (sure, it's only 3 at the moment, but this method hardly scales).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably by design there's no link to the election list: when an election is over, there isn't a direct link anywhere to the list, either. Normally, `/election` is for the actual election, but the election list as a placeholder during the off-season.

To that end, if you supply an unused number (like `0`), you'll get the whole list. Try:

> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/0

With the caveat that the list doesn't think there's an election going on right now.

Comment: Ah, that'll do nicely as a general work-around. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Workaround - visit the list of moderators in [/about](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/about). Below every moderator there is a link to the election they won.